# facebook getting user id from graph api via taggable_friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In v1.0 API I was able to get friends with their facebook ID like this:

```
{
      "name": "Somename SomeSurname", 
      "id": "100007797060798"
 }
```

In the v2.0 I can use only taggable_friends to get this information, however `i must have missed something in the documentation, because the id I'm getting is like this (id is always different):

```
{
      "id": "AaKJ-QN8OlY3m-2DHeVnc5oQZFnx_V0ptUF8XFEstr3EcS1LltvAx0_xptve3DWc_vI1zP0s4RhVMOTk1EqDvzCHMkEqFRMIkuXtyXe5d9O1-Q", 
      "name": "Somename someSurname"
}
```

can someone point me where I can retrieve a real ID out of this?

Comment: Do you need to get friends of a particular user?

Comment: just a friends of logged in user.

Comment: you need to request for "user_friends" permission while creating access token for that user.

Comment: Hey Webduvet !! I am getting same issue as you.. If you found the solution of your problem than please help me,'

Comment: @BevinPatel, yes, as a matter of fact I did find a solution to go around this. I'm using phone numbers and SMS to acquire users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to get to id via taggable_friends endpoint.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: Is it possible the reverse way? Get taggable id from user id?

Comment: Don't think so. But when you tag a user that do not have your app installed facebook creates an app_scoped_user_id behind the scene. This id is possible to retrieve by querying the instance_id returned from the action. I have not tested to use that ID to tag the user again, but that might work :)

Comment: I still can't believe that I am not able to identify taggable friends. It is very limited how to deal with facebook api.

Answer (score 3):

`/me/taggable_friends` shows all friends in the list except for some. In one case, there are 326 friends in a profile but this only shows 317 and in another profile there are 194 friends in total but it only shows 182.

```
$flist = $fb->api('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name,id&limit=1000');
```

shows almost all friends in the list (despite the limit being too high) but leaves some of them in both cases. This might not work on the api explorer if your app is not approved and published but it will work for admins, testers and developers of your application.

You cannot decode this id because that would defeat the purpose of encoding it in the first place.

What I am also wondering is that whether it is possible to invite friends of a user to use the application?

Comment: It was retrieving 25 friends, when i add the limit it retrieve all friends ,,

Answer (score 0):

may be you can get id by search people with the same picture.

```
me?fields=taggable_friends{name,picture}

{
        "name": "ปาณิศา หลานตากอย.ตาแก้ว คงเพ็ชร",
        "picture": {
          "data": {
            "url": "https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/19113605_1931156107168776_605762913793659652_n.jpg?oh=951c7c13a85b0ce3abe8a6e7bacae127&oe=59DA354A&__gda__=1508078042_6baaa5dc05f7b1e85f7a90e8c21e517b"
          }
        },
        "last_name": "คงเพ็ชร",
        "first_name": "ปาณิศา",
        "id": "AaKW3BwqCsT_4IspPO5jlFZet-4LnXQfulxsumuI-4Mel7M-0cTX-7gbARaOJSy7JMbLDBcwCEMdBvJQmZ7-YNEN-o_EDpugQfY02UqjED_uvQ"
      }
```

then

```
search?type=user&q=ปาณิศา หลานตากอย.ตาแก้ว คงเพ็ชร&fields=id,name,picture


"data": [
{
  "id": "1519971271620597",
  "name": "ปาณิศา หลานตากอย.ตาแก้ว คงเพ็ชร",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/19113605_1931156107168776_605762913793659652_n.jpg?oh=21c44649424500928d0299291414f1aa&oe=59A27344&__gda__=1508317043_a83bb236c462cd9d179f8e949cea801f"
    }
  }
}
```

]

the two results have same url filename **19113605_1931156107168776_605762913793659652_n.jpg**
then you can get id from search result **1519971271620597**

Answer (score -2):

or use link: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=about
it return facebook Id and you can insert into your DB.

Comment: he is looking for friend id not logged in user's

Answer (score -6):

You need to request for "user_friends" permission while creating access token for that user.

After that you can make a call to graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=friends
```

and it will return the results in following format:

```
{
  "friends": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Dummy1",
        "id": "454####455"
      },
      {
        "name": "Dummy2",
        "id": "82####374"
      },
      {
        "name": "Dummy3",
        "id": "10###7277"
      },

    ]
  },
  "id": "14###1568"
}
```

Comment: this gives me only friends who accepted the app. not very useful for what I want.

Comment: @SankalpBhatt how can i get all friends? i want all friends of particular user with id.

Comment: question on this: I was able to do it in the browser (outside the context of an app) and I still got a long list of friends... Does it mean that if you make a web request you still get the full list?
Edit: it is not the complete list, but then how does FB knows an "app context"?

Comment: Outdated... u cant use it in v2.0 >