# Facebook taggable_friends doesn't return all friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

I'm trying to get friends list using /me/taggable_friends endpoint and got missing entities.
Facebook account has 50 friends, production app(having permission) returns 48, staging(i'm app admin) - 25.
There are no information for this issue on [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends)
.
Best of my searches - a few comments from users with approvance of this, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/28561358/3987768 but without any explanations.

Comment: file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ - btw, i assume you know the limitations of taggable_friends? do you actually want to tag users?

Comment: Yes, i know limitations of usage. Permission was already approved by facebook.

Comment: Does the response show a paging link? Your best option is to file a bug report as @luschn already suggested.

Comment: Yes, some objects was paginated. I was surprised that per page default value was different for staging & prod fb apps.
Finally, two friends, not listed into api, just was deactivated.